# How to scrape ratings data from Google search Jobs site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a website scraper for [Google Jobs site](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Data+Engineer%22+%22Netherlands%22+%22Job%22&sca_esv=559003401&source=hp&ei=617kZIHuM5SK9u8PgOW_yA0&iflsig=AD69kcEAAAAAZORs-7H_KqXwpEx6fX9Rt1qIemhf4-8K&uact=5&oq=%22Data+Engineer%22+%22Netherlands%22+%22Job%22&gs_lp=Egdnd3Mtd2l6IiMiRGF0YSBFbmdpbmVlciIgIk5ldGhlcmxhbmRzIiAiSm9iIjIIEAAYCBgHGB4yCBAAGAgYBxgeMgYQABgIGB5IkpgBUKYKWLiUAXAFeACQAQCYAYUBoAHuEKoBBDM4LjG4AQPIAQD4AQGoAgDCAgYQABgHGB7CAgsQABiABBixAxiDAcICDBAuGAcYHhjHARjRA8ICCBAAGIAEGLEDwgILEC4YgAQYxwEYrwHCAgUQLhiABMICBRAAGIAEwgIHEAAYDRiABMICCBAAGAcYHhgKwgIGEAAYHhgNwgIIEAAYCBgeGA3CAggQABgHGB4YE8ICCRAAGA0YExiABMICChAAGAUYBxgeGBPCAgoQABgIGAcYHhgTwgIHEAAYExiABMICBhAAGB4YE8ICCBAAGAUYHhgTwgIIEAAYCBgeGBPCAggQABgWGB4YEw&sclient=gws-wiz&ibp=htl;jobs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjC-d3V2u-AAxUMgv0HHd1DBjsQudcGKAF6BAgTEDo#htivrt=jobs&fpstate=tldetail&htichips=&htischips=&htidocid=Ioj1U-HpmKwAAAAAAAAAAA%3D%3D), and I am using the Python requests library alongside BeautifulSoup4. Upon making the get request to the URL from my code, I was able to retrieve the HTML output, which I then parsed using BeautifulSoup. However, I noticed I can't find the HTML content for the "ratings" area (as in the picture below) of the job pages.

[Ratings section of Google jobs pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6ZUA.png).

[Full sample page view for a job page with the area covered by div of class 'pE8vnd avtvi'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbzu6.png)

Here is what I have implemented so far

```
res = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': '...'})
site = res.text

content = bs4.BeautifulSoup(site, 'html.parser')

##'pE8vnd avtvi' is the class of the div element containing the whole job detail page
vals = content.find_all('div', class_ = 'pE8vnd avtvi')
    
with open('./index.html', 'w') as f:
   f.write(vals[0])
```

When I open the 'index.html' file, and I inspect up until the bottom, I don't find the div containing the ratings section, as I can normally see when I check DevTools in my browser. I have tried for as many of the jobs as possible, by changing the index of 'vals' which I write to index.html, but the output never contains the div.

Is there something I may be missing out?

Answer (score 0):

Google Jobs uses dynamic rendering, meaning when you fetch the page with requests you're getting pre-rendered HTML, so JavaScript hasn't been ran yet which is most likely responsible for the data you are trying to get.

There are a few things you can do, the first and most likely the easiest is to use Selenium.

### 1. Use Selenium

Selenium is a Python library that allows you to use a web browser like Chrome automated with Python. Here's how you can set it up:

First install selenium:

```
pip install selenium
```

Next install a  webdriver, if you go to your default webbrowser and type it's name followed by `://version` e.g. `chrome://version` you will find the version you need to download. You can then search for "[browser name] selenium webdriver" into google and download the version that matches your browser.

Here is a simple selenium script using Chrome that will open your browser and go to google.com:

```
from selenium import webdriver

# If the driver executable isn't in your PATH, you'd specify it directly via:
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path_to_driver/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print(driver.title)

driver.quit()
```

Then you can use requests and bs4 along side it to scrape the data you need.

### 2. Check Network Tab

Google Jobs may offer an API endpoint to pull in the jobs, you may be able to use this same endpoint to get the data you are wanting. If you inspect the data being pulled in the network tab when you go to the page, you might find the API that gets jobs.

If none of these things suit you, I'm sure that you can also find some other ways to do this, I'd start by searching Dynamic page scraping and going from there mate.